# Using time() and setTime() functions in PHP and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, date, utc

I would like to have a javascript date object having its time set according to the web server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var date=new Date();

date.setTime(<?php echo time() ?>);

alert(date.toString()); //displays the date and time according to the timezone set on the client's computer

</script>
```

Is the above code reliable?

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: Reliable in what respect? It's likely to be off a second or two sometimes if a response takes a lot of time, but other than that... it should be okay

Comment: you want to seek help from NTP ? http://www.ntp.org/

Comment: @ajreal: Thanks for suggesting NTP. My web app is not a critical one, it's just for fun, so it should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's not.

Since [Javascript's `setTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) works with milliseconds and [PHP's `time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) works with seconds.

You'll need to add some stuff to make it works ;) I'll let you find out what.

Comment: So won't `date.setTime(<?php echo time() ?> * 1000)` suffice to solve this difference?

Comment: Seriously? You don't want to make the OP thinks by himself or you just like spoon-feeding? Anyway, as @Pekka said, it won't be reliable because of response time.

Comment: It's just some unit conversion so the spoon is not really a big one. Thank you so much for pointing out the error in my code :)

Comment: more like giving all the help possible but I can see your point. Sometimes those trivial things take hours for newbies to figure out so I prefer to save them those hours.